# How do I create a link without the URL being visible in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

As part of printing the `console.log` for a Javascript project, I need to print a URL without showing it to the user. It should work like this:
[Click Here](https://www.google.com/)

Upon clicking the 'Click Here' text, I should be able to redirect the user to the given link, and the user should not get to see the link.

Request someone to help with this.

Comment: “See it” where exactly? In the browser status bar? Or in the address bar, _after_ they have been navigated to the target URL (URL cloaking)? And what does the console have to do with this?

Comment: One way or another, the user is going to see the link.

Comment: @Lain I just want the 'Click Here' text to be visible. I don't mind the user seeing the link once he opens the page.

Comment: What is the actual use-case on this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution?

```
<a onClick="window.location.href='https://google.com';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `href` attribute to your anchor tag. This `href` will be shown to the user in the bottom left. But you could do something like this:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.href='http:\\www.google.com'">Link</a>
```

The javascript in the `href` will do literally nothing. And the javascript in the `onclick` function will redirect to the link.

Unfortunately the user sees something like this in the bottom left:

[image: anchor href shown in the bottom left]

Answer (score 0):

May be little indirect way like this.

```
<a href="javascript:var w=window,a2b=w.atob;w.location=a2b(a2b('YUhSMGNITTZMeTluYjI5bmJHVXVZMjl0'))"> Click Here </a>
```

Its actually very simple.
Just using base64 encoded value twice (or some other encryption logic).

**But note any client side code is never secure.**

Example:
If you use encryption, there is no way you can call decryption without storing the key in client variable.